# While using POST method in POSTMAN,integer value (Without Quotes) is getting converted to String in output.How to stop(Validate)it?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, annotations, postman

I am doing POST for this Json record,defaultValue(2nd row) is actually a String field,but even if i give an integer value WITHOUT QUOTES,it accepts and converts it into a String in json output,How do i validate it and provide a error message in the json output(e.g. Invalid String).

```
{
    "fieldName": "ID Field",
    "defaultValue": 1234,
    "operationType": {
        "operationTypeId": 1027,
        "operationTypeName": "Header",
        "operationCode": "67"
    },
    "dataFileType": {
        "dataFileTypeId": 259,
        "dataFileTypeDesc": "membership enrollment file for Accolade Bank",
        "externalRef": null,
        "fileFormat": "xml",
        "fileCategory": "Interface",
        "fileDelimiter": null,
        "xsdFile": "MBO Issuer Membership File.xsd",
        "fileShortName": "MasterCard_UK_accolade.xml",
        "slaHours": 2,
        "hasHeader": true,
        "hasTrailer": true
    }
}


{

"fieldName": "ID Field",
"defaultValue": "1234",
"operationType": {
    "operationTypeId": 1027,
    "operationTypeName": "Header",
    "operationCode": "67"
},
"dataFileType": {
    "dataFileTypeId": 259,
    "dataFileTypeDesc": "membership enrollment file for Accolade Bank",
    "externalRef": null,
    "fileFormat": "xml",
    "fileCategory": "Interface",
    "fileDelimiter": null,
    "xsdFile": "MBO Issuer Membership File.xsd",
    "fileShortName": "MasterCard_UK_accolade.xml",
    "slaHours": 2,
    "hasHeader": true,
    "hasTrailer": true
    }
}
```

The integer value given for defaultValue field has been converted into String in output json,but the actual output should be some error message telling for e.g. "Insert only String value for defaultValue field ".....Thanks

Comment: Why not just validate the input on java endpoint? Try  `Integer.parseInt(defaultValueFromJson) ` ... if this throws an exception then the input was not in a correct format i.e. it was not a number.